# How to sort a list by self defined order?

Tags: sorting, grails, groovy

I want to use Groovy to sort following list by a defined order

```
def ls = [ 'sperson_firstname', 'a_id', 'a_name', 'scontact_street', 'scontact_email',  'sperson_nationality', 'scontact_tel', 'sperson _birthday', 'sperson_lastname', 'scontact_fax']
```

After sort should be sorted like this:

```
 ls = ['a_id', 'a_name', 'sperson_firstname', 'sperson_lastname', 'sperson _birthday','sperson_nationality','scontact_street', 'scontact_email',  'scontact_tel', 'scontact_fax']
```

that means my defined order should sort prefix first like

```
[a , sperson, scontact]
```

Then for each prefix should sort its suffix with a defined order

e.g. for prefix **sperson** should sort like

```
['sperson_firstname', 'sperson_lastname', 'sperson _birthday','sperson_nationality']
```

for prefix **scontact** should sort like

```
['scontact_street', 'scontact_email',  'scontact_tel', 'scontact_fax']
```

I have tried

```
def sortOrder = ["a","sperson","scontact"]
ls.sort{ls -> sortOrder.indexOf(ls.split("_")[0]) }
```

but this can only solve the prefix sorting ...

Comment: read this : [http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Apache-Common/BeanComparatorSortingbasedonPropertiesofclass.htm](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Apache-Common/BeanComparatorSortingbasedonPropertiesofclass.htm)

Comment: Why would `sperson_birthday` come after `sperson_firstname`

Comment: what i tried pls see edit. because i have a far more complex list need to be sorted...it's for export as Header of a excel doc.

Comment: Because a similar more complex list need to be as header of an excel doc... the header of this excel is defined order, not alphabet sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you are doing and extend it for the prefix:

```
List prefixOrder = ['a' , 'sperson', 'scontact']
Map suffixOrdersByPrefix = [
    a: [...],
    b: [...],
    c: [...]
]
def indexOfComparator = { list, a, b -> 
   list.indexOf(a).compareTo(list.indexOf(b)) 
}
def prefixComparator = { a, b -> 
   indexOfComparator(prefixOrder, a, b)
}
def suffixComparator = { prefix, a, b ->
   indexOfComparator(suffixOrdersByPrefix[prefix], a, b)
}

l.sort { a, b ->
    List<String> aTokens = a.tokenize('_'),
        bTokens = b.tokenize('_')
    prefixComparator(aTokens.first(), bTokens.first()) ?:
        suffixComparator(aTokens.first(), aTokens.last(), bTokens.last())
}
```

You compare the prefixes, if there are equal (i.e comparation returns 0) you compare the suffixes. You can map the order per suffix using... well, a map :).

Answer (score 0):

Your approach wasn't that far off. I just used a two-dimensional array (actually a list of lists I guess), where the first element is the prefix and the following are the suffixes for that index. Then the order is just a weighted prefix score plus the suffix score.

```
def ls = ['sperson_firstname', 'a_id', 'a_name', 'scontact_street', 'scontact_email',  'sperson_nationality', 'scontact_tel', 'sperson_birthday', 'sperson_lastname', 'scontact_fax']

def sortOrder = [
    ['a','id','name'],
    ['sperson','firstname','lastname','birthday','nationality'],
    ['scontact','street','email','tel','fax']
]

ls.sort{item ->
    def preIndex = sortOrder.collect{it[0]}.indexOf(item.split('_')[0])
    def postIndex = sortOrder[preIndex][1..(sortOrder[preIndex].size-1)].indexOf(item.split('_')[1])
    return (preIndex * 10) + postIndex
}

assert ['a_id', 'a_name', 'sperson_firstname', 'sperson_lastname', 'sperson_birthday', 'sperson_nationality', 'scontact_street', 'scontact_email', 'scontact_tel', 'scontact_fax'] == ls
```